# Returning Entries in Windows 10 Context Menu

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I would like to remove some entries from the Windows Context Menu (I am using Windows 10 x64 1809), the problem is that they return on every explorer refresh. For instance I am doing this to remove 'Include in library' entry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Library Location]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Library Location]
```

Then I explicitly set permissions to deny access to the parent key and every inherited key for every account that isn't mine. I also added this script to autostart. Windows 10 however doesn't care about any of this, on every explorer refresh these entries return. Even despite the fact that recreated keys have still their permissions set to deny. I would really like to avoid force executing this script on every right click.

Bounty goes to a person who can show me how to PERMANENTLY remove these entries.

// EDIT 1

I was asked what other entries I am trying to remove, actually I am trying to get rid of: pin to ..., include in library, and send to:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{90AA3A4E-1CBA-4233-B8BB-535773D48449}]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\pintohome]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\pintohome]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Library Location]
[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\Library Location]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\SendTo]
@=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
@=""
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.Website\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mscfile\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
```

Removing associated CLSIDs and denying access to them doesn't work either.

I fail to understand why permissions are even implemented if windows just bypasses them without hestitation.

// EDIT 2

Even if this bounty expires and sb provides a correct answer to this problem at any given point I am gonna make sure that person receives 50 rep.

Comment: Have you considered that these might be default values for the shell and by denying the shell the ability to see or use those keys that they are returned to the default?  This is a nice puzzle.. I will think about it. :)

Comment: Yes I did, but I started denying access BECAUSE they were recreated. So it was the other way around.

Comment: Have you tried disabling libraries?  I don't have any option for adding to libraries in my context menus.  I believe it's because I disabled libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I  apologize in advance for the simplton answer... Relevant only for the "Include In Library" option.

Taken from [TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4222-hide-show-libraries-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html)

1. Open File Explorer Option
2. Go to the "View" tab
3. Uncheck "Navigation Pane->Show Libraries"

Even if this solution does not fit your needs (doing it via the registry) - it might be the reason for the override once restarting explorer...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already done that when installing the system long time ago :). It has no effect.